# Silverlight GDR 1 Ruined my Developer Tools. Now I can't debug in VS2010

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, download

I have `Silverlight 4.0.50524`, but I have `Silverlight SDK 4.0.50401`. This makes me not able to debug Silverlight apps in VS2010. Can anyone point me to a download link for the Silverlight 4 GDR 1 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://silverlight.net/getstarted: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039 is the Windows Dev runtime.

Comment: That seems to have fixed my issue; I thought I'd tried those links, but maybe I had uninstalled and reinstalled different combo of SL + Dev Runtime.